# How to add a property (property name is variable) to object via MongoDB driver (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, object-properties

The structure of my document in collection is this.

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("54e74de2950fd3a4e5f0a37a"),
"userName": "Any_user",
"ratings": {
   "rating1" : [ ],
   "big_rating" : [ ] 
  }
}
```

In MongoDB client (mongo.exe) the adding i need looks like this

```
db.userContent.update({userName: "NXTaar"}, {$set: {"ratings.variable_name": []}})
```

I need the function for the MongoDB node.js driver
And yes, i know the "property name as string" thing there i can pass the variable to the property name. Here is what i tried to make:

```
var rating = {};
var title = 'some_string';
ratings[title] = [];

usercontent.update({userName: "some_user"}, {$set: ratings}, function (err, doc) {...})
```

this line adds a new object to the document with a name of property

```
usercontent.update({userName: "some_user"}, {$set: {ratings: ratings}}, function (err, doc) {...})
```

and this one does exactly what i need, but each time it runs, it rewrites current property with a new one(yes, i know, it because of $set parameter which changes selected object with the thing that you've passed to it)

I need a function which adds a property to object with a name given through variable

Comment: You might want to look after doing a mapReduce: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/

Answer (score 6):

Like so:

```
var t = "property_name"
var field_name = "ratings." + t
var update = { "$set" : { } }
update["$set"][field_qname] = []
db.usercontent.update({ "userName" : "some_user" }, update)
```

Construct the proper dot notation field name and then the proper `$set` update expression, then pass that to the `update` function.